# Plot is drawing extra line across the graph

Tags: python

```
    nsteps = 100
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100)
    
    x = np.zeros(nsteps + 1)
    n0 =  np.zeros(nsteps + 1)

    x[0] = x0
    for n in range(nsteps):
            x[n+1] = k*x[n]*(1.0 - x[n])
            n0[n] = n
            print(f'n = {n0[n]}, x(n) = {x[n]}')
#            plt.plot(n0, x, color ='r')

    
#    plt.scatter(n0, x, color ='r',
#                              label=f"$k$ = {k:.1f}, $x(0)$ = {x0:.1f} ")
    plt.plot(n0, x, color ='b',
                              label=f"$k$ = {k:.1f}, $x(0)$ = {x0:.1f} ")
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.xlabel("n")
    plt.ylabel("x")
    plt.xlim(0,100)
```

I am trying to plot a graph of x values at step n that depends on x value from pervious step:

x[n+1] = k*x[n]*(1.0 - x[n]) for n =0 to 100, x[0] = 0.5, k = 3.5

I tried to plot excluding end points but cannot get rid of line

Here is the image of my plot
[plot showing line across](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc2sh.png)

Comment: What plotting library are you using? matplotlib? seaborn? Please [edit] and add the tag for it. Also make sure you're providing a [mre]; this indentation is wrong.

Comment: Your `n[100]` is 0. Just `n = np.arange(1, nsteps+1)` instead of trying to construct it in the loop.

Comment: The problem is that the way you're filling `n0` inside loop implies that `n0[-1]` (last values is equal to `0`. then the last value is misplaced. replace `n0[n] = n` for `n0[n+1]=n+1` and problem solved

Comment: Yes, using matplotlib

Comment: indentation:  I tried several times to indent but just could not do it...obviously missing something.  sorry